# Help with this proof of inequality

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that n($a_1a_2.....a_n$)$\leq$($a_1^n + a_2^n + a_3^n.....a_n^n$)
I tried using AM GM inequality but I got $n^n$ and $(a_1+a_2....a_n)^n$. I got these two terms If anyone could help me or hint me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $a_i\ge 0$, this is a direct application of AM-GM indeed

$$\frac{\sum a_i^n}n\ge \sqrt[n]{\prod a_i^n}=  \sqrt[n]{\left(\prod a_i\right)^n}=\prod a_i$$

otherwise, as noticed, it is not true.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's impossible to prove this inequality.

Try, $n=3$,  $a_1=a_2=1$ and $a_3=-3$.

Comment: I think it is not mentioned in the question but all the $\ {a}_{i}$'s belong to $\ \mathbb{R}^{+} $

Comment: @Vishnu Kadiri  But I don't see it. Maybe in this just is a general problem of the topic-starter. In any case, thank you for your interest!

Comment: They belong to $\ \mathbb{R}^{+}$ Anyways thanks

Comment: @BlackThunder You are welcome! For non-negative variables your inequality it's just AM-GM.

Answer (score 3):

This is a direct application of AM-GM inequality:
$$\ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} {{a}_{i}}^{n}}{n} \geq {(\prod_{i=1}^{n} {{a}_{i}}^{n})}^{\frac{1}{n}}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{a}_{i}$$